# Montonicity of polynomial

Tags: calculus

Does there exist a polynomial which is strictly increasing and has strictly concavity up throughout or strictly decreasing and strictly concavity down throughout?The answer was given  there exists no such polynomial but I think e^x must satisfy both strictly increasing and concavity up throughout.Whereas using Taylor series we can write e^x as 1+x+(x^2)/2 +(x^3)/6 +..... 
What's wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to show that every polynomial of odd degree has a root and takes on both positive and negative values. In order for a polynomial function to be strictly increasing, it therefore must be of odd degree, because its derivative must be strictly positive. However, the second derivative is then of odd degree (or zero in the case of a degree $1$ polynomial), so the function cannot always be concave up because this will take both positive and negative values.

Your example doesn't work because $e^x$ is not a polynomial. If you want to think in terms of Taylor series, a function is a polynomial if and only if its Taylor series has only finitely many terms.

Comment: I am claiming that e^x is an infinite degree polynomial,it is strictly increasing and concavity is up throughout.

Comment: @Mayank "infinite degree polynomial" is a contradiction. A function is a polynomial precisely because it is of finite degree.